# Git: per-branch level access and maximum number of branches

Tags: git, github, branch, token

I have a few Git/Github questions. First, is there a way to create some kind of access token for pull/push access to just **one** branch on a Git repo? The idea is I'd give a user this access token, and they can use it but only to push/pull on one branch that I've specified in advance.

Second, is there a upper bound on the number of branches a repo can have? Say I have 100 branches. Does this impact performance? What about 10,000? 1,000,000 branches?

Comment: The only think that comes close is GitHub's `protected branches` in which you can't commit without making a PR. There is no limit on branches I'm aware of, but remember that git stores everything in a big tree of `objects` so the bigger the tree, eventually the slower will be the repository traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *number of branches* is theoretically unbounded: provided you have an infinite amount of space in which to store all the branch names and their IDs, you can create any arbitrary number of branches, all pointing to a single commit.  This means the repository itself, not counting the branch names, can have a small, bounded size (one commit containing one file), with 1 [googolplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex) names all pointing to that one single commit.

Each name must, however, be unique, and each name occupies some space.  In current Git implementations, branch names are stored in individual files (`.git/refs/heads/br/an/ch` holds the value for the branch named `br/an/ch`) and/or in a single flat file (`.git/packed-refs` holds the value for every reference, including all branch names).<sup>1</sup>  Since this file / these files live within the repository, they will occupy space, and probably the host will limit you at some point (certainly at the point where it runs out of disk space, but probably well before then).

---

<sup>1</sup>If a name appears in an individual file, that file gives the value for the name.  If not, Git falls back to searching the flat file.  Hence, for a name that exists in both the flat file *and* its own private file, the private file value overrides.  This lets Git simply collect all the names into the flat file, removing the individual files, to re-compress; and then re-create individual files one at a time whenever a name is updated.  Only name *deletion* requires updating both the individual file (remove it) *and* the flat file (remove the entry).